# Android 10 Enabled Magnification is not working properly on my device

Tags: android, android-10.0, magnific-popup, accessibilityservice, magnification

I checked android 10 emulator magnification is working fine, but not working on my Android mobiles (Android Version 10). I used the adb commands to enable Magnification API's but not working. Thanks in Advance